# Dual boot not working in windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu in my windows computer. After installing Ubuntu, there is no grub option in the startup menu. Instead, the computer restarts with windows as usual. But when I checked the disk for allocation, I could see linux as installed. Also, when I went to recovery in the windows for advanced restart, I could see Ubuntu as installed. But when I restarted with Ubuntu, I get the message BIOS is disabled. I even checked the BIOS, but it shows enbaled status. Please let me know what mistake I am making.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork. Also, showing screen shots (digital photos) of the error messages you mention may be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Even I faced a similar issue while dual booting. On researching, I found that in Windows 10, the grub is not loaded by default by the BIOS. We need to explicitly provide the path once, so that it will load the GRUB everytime at restart. This will only work if you have successfully installed Ubuntu, but only facing the GRUB issue.

To load GRUB at startup, to the following:

1. Boot into Windows 10
2. Open the Command Prompt(in Administrator Mode). Go to Start -> Command Prompt -> Right Click and "Run as Administrator".
3. type in the following command and press enter:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
   ```
4. Now Restart your system, and the GRUB menu should be loaded. Select the OS you want to boot into.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're Welcome! Do mark the answer as accepted. It will help others as well @HobbesianThinker

Comment: This works well i run into this issue when i swapped drives and when i swapped back the GRUB bootloader was gone. Running the command restored the bootloader.

Comment: Yes. Everytime the bootloader fails to load, this command helps! @ErikvanBerkum

Comment: I did this. Now, I'm not able to load windows at all. Any idea how to undo this from UEFI/BIOS?